# Sobre projeto em Vue em uma pasta específica consumindo dados do Laravel via RESTfull API

Tags: laravel, vue.js

É possível / boa prática criar um projeto em Vue em uma pasta separada do Laravel de modo que toda a autenticação e o consumo de dados seja feito via RESTfull API do Laravel?

```
/Raiz
    /Front <- Arquivos Vue
    /Back <- Arquivos Laravel
```

Já li na documentação do Laravel que dentro da pasta resources existe um exemplo de implementação em Vue. Mas o fato é que eu gostaria de usar o vue template webpack e todos os seus recursos.

Comment: Oi Flávio, acho a tua pergunta fora de escopo pois há _N_ respostas certas para ela... eu diria "sim", toda a estrutura que organize os ficheiros é boa estrutura.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boa tarde!

É possível sim.

No arquivo routes/api.php do Laravel você pode definir as rotas e suas respectivas funções.

Aí basta no seu projeto em Vue requisitar essas URLs que você definiu para consumir e manipular os dados.

Para acessar as rotas definidas no arquivo api.php é necessário adicionar "api/" antes do nome da rota.

Por exemplo, se a seguinte rota foi definida:

```
Route::get('foo', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

A URL para acessa-la seria: `localhost/api/foo`.